# Menu link adds one after another - data from mysql database

Tags: php, html

I created a nav menu where menu data comes from database.

My problem is:

When I click on first link

http://localhost/root/as/slider1.php/1/Real%20Estate

When I click on second link

http://localhost/root/as/slider1.php/1/slider1.php/2/Cars

When I click on third link

http://localhost/root/as/slider1.php/1/slider1.php/2/slider1.php/3/Electronics

When I click on fourth link

http://localhost/root/as/slider1.php/1/slider1.php/2/slider1.php/3/slider1.php/4/Furniture

only first page is opening. after that no page opens. I do not understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: User absolute links, not relative

Comment: @Peon This is **href='slider1/" . $row['cat_id'] . "/" . $row['product'] . "'**  of links

Comment: Use links like **href='/root/as/slider1/" . $row['cat_id'] . "/" . $row['product']**

Comment: Thanks my problem solved. Plz answer so that the question wil get answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should add slashes `/` on links begin.